# How to get the whole html content when visiting a page of splited wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, string-conversion

I am doing string conversion for every post/page in Wordpress. I add below function to `template_redirect` hook to get the whole html content and do the conversion.

```
function my_string_conversing() {
    obstart( 'ob_callback' );
    return;
}

function ob_callback( $buffer ) {
    // doing conversion here...
    return $buffer
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_string_conversion' );
```

These code works well for posts and pages, but if I split one post into multiple pages, then this will not work. It even don't run `my_string_conversion` function when click each page of a split post. How can I make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, use `add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_string_conversion', -100 );` instead.